# My parity node ran out of space- I have over 100GB free and am using warp-barrier. Is this normal?

Tags: parity

Error message below. This doesn't seem right, I'm only downloading a little over 20k blocks (which is the whole point of warp barrier), how can this really need more than 100GB? Just to clarify, it won't even sync. It's not the case that it synced and then X weeks later ran out of space (that I could understand).

[image: I include an image of the error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--warp-barrier` doesn't prevent you from downloading "ancient blocks" (you still do that in the background) it only prevents you from downloading older *snapshots* (which define where your sync will start after you are done warping) than you specify. If you don't want to ever download or verify "ancient" blocks, ie, blocks that are below the block number you warped to, you need to use `--no-ancient-blocks`.

Comment: Ok I've been looking more into this, and I am very confused. --warp (this is enabled by default so can be ignored) will download 'a recent' snapshot, restore it, and sync from that point. --warp-barrier, like you say will not download a snapshot below that number. This implies that -warp is NOT downloading the most recent snapshot by default- if it did, --warp-barrier would serve no purpose. So why not? Why can't the default sync (ie -warp) only download the most recent snapshot?

Comment: And I'm unable to find documentation for --no-ancient-blocks on the parity site. I take it, what it means, is that unless this is enabled, after it has synced, it will continue to download old blocks all the way back to genesis? So unless I have 1TB to spare I MUST use --no-ancient-blocks, would this be correct?

Comment: https://wiki.parity.io/Warp-Sync from the wiki warp sync gets "the full state at a given block extremely quickly, and then [fills] in the blocks between the genesis and the snapshot in the background"

Comment: A full node, without using `--pruning archive` will only be around 150gb.

Comment: And to answer why warp doesn't only download the most recent snapshot: it tries. It asks peers for what snapshot they have, and since snapshots are quite intensive to generate, "the most recent snapshot" found among the closest peers to you might actually be quite old - warp-barrier ensures you ignore those first responses and wait until you see a snapshot above your warp-barrier.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanations, they help a lot. So it is interesting to hear that a full node without archive mode is 150GB. I take it this means that all the blocks are only 150GB- does the archive version include all the states after each block? From memory that's what it is. I saw it explained elsewhere as a 'block explorer DB'

Comment: Yep - states after every single block, and it might be referred to as that as you only really need to have that information if you are running a block explorer 